# Directx 11 Bitblt Alternative

Tags: c++, directx, bsod, bitblt

I have the following function which I am trying to integrate into my directx 11 application.  When I am using directx9 everything works fine but when converting to directx 11 I am getting a blue screen of death error at the Bitblt line (I must be doing something wrong with the HDC's?).  I was wondering what the best way to convert this code to directx 11 compatible surfaces instead of HDC's would be.

Here is the function:

```
void CFlashDXPlayer::DrawFrame(HDC dc)
{
if (m_dirtyFlag)
{
    IViewObject* pViewObject = NULL;
    m_flashInterface->QueryInterface(IID_IViewObject, (LPVOID*) &pViewObject);
    if (pViewObject != NULL)
    {
        // Combine regions
        HRGN unionRgn, first, second = NULL;
        unionRgn = CreateRectRgnIndirect(&m_dirtyRects[0]);
        if (m_dirtyRects.size() >= 2)
            second = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 1, 1);

        for (std::vector<RECT>::iterator it = m_dirtyRects.begin() + 1; it != m_dirtyRects.end(); ++it)
        {
            // Fill combined region
            first = unionRgn;
            SetRectRgn(second, it->left, it->top, it->right, it->bottom);
            unionRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 1, 1);

            CombineRgn(unionRgn, first, second, RGN_OR);
            DeleteObject(first);
        }

        if (second)
            DeleteObject(second);

        RECT clipRgnRect; GetRgnBox(unionRgn, &clipRgnRect);
        RECTL clipRect = { 0, 0, m_width, m_height };

        // Fill background
        if (m_transpMode != TMODE_FULL_ALPHA)
        {
            // Set clip region
            SelectClipRgn(dc, unionRgn);

            COLORREF fillColor = GetBackgroundColor();
            HBRUSH fillColorBrush = CreateSolidBrush(fillColor);
            FillRgn(dc, unionRgn, fillColorBrush);
            DeleteObject(fillColorBrush);

            // Draw to main buffer
            HRESULT hr = pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_TRANSPARENT, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, dc, &clipRect, &clipRect, NULL, 0);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        }
        else
        {
            if (m_alphaBlackDC == NULL)
            {
                // Create memory buffers
                BITMAPINFOHEADER bih = {0};
                bih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
                bih.biBitCount = 32;
                bih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
                bih.biPlanes = 1;
                bih.biWidth = LONG(m_width);
                bih.biHeight = -LONG(m_height);

                m_alphaBlackDC = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
                m_alphaBlackBitmap = CreateDIBSection(m_alphaBlackDC, (BITMAPINFO*)&bih, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&m_alphaBlackBuffer, 0, 0);
                SelectObject(m_alphaBlackDC, m_alphaBlackBitmap);

                m_alphaWhiteDC = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
                m_alphaWhiteBitmap = CreateDIBSection(m_alphaWhiteDC, (BITMAPINFO*)&bih, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&m_alphaWhiteBuffer, 0, 0);
                SelectObject(m_alphaWhiteDC, m_alphaWhiteBitmap);
            }

            HRESULT hr;
            HBRUSH fillColorBrush;

            // Render frame twice - against white and against black background to calculate alpha
            SelectClipRgn(m_alphaBlackDC, unionRgn);

            COLORREF blackColor = 0x00000000;
            fillColorBrush = CreateSolidBrush(blackColor);
            FillRgn(m_alphaBlackDC, unionRgn, fillColorBrush);
            DeleteObject(fillColorBrush);

            hr = pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_TRANSPARENT, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, m_alphaBlackDC, &clipRect, &clipRect, NULL, 0);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

            // White background
            SelectClipRgn(m_alphaWhiteDC, unionRgn);

            COLORREF whiteColor = 0x00FFFFFF;
            fillColorBrush = CreateSolidBrush(whiteColor);
            FillRgn(m_alphaWhiteDC, unionRgn, fillColorBrush);
            DeleteObject(fillColorBrush);

            hr = pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_TRANSPARENT, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, m_alphaWhiteDC, &clipRect, &clipRect, NULL, 0);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

            // Combine alpha
            for (LONG y = clipRgnRect.top; y < clipRgnRect.bottom; ++y)
            {
                int offset = y * m_width * 4 + clipRgnRect.left * 4;
                for (LONG x = clipRgnRect.left; x < clipRgnRect.right; ++x)
                {
                    BYTE blackRed = m_alphaBlackBuffer[offset];
                    BYTE whiteRed = m_alphaWhiteBuffer[offset];
                    m_alphaBlackBuffer[offset + 3] = 255 - (whiteRed - blackRed);
                    offset += 4;
                }
            }

            // Blit result to target DC
            BitBlt(dc, clipRgnRect.left, clipRgnRect.top,
                   clipRgnRect.right - clipRgnRect.left,
                   clipRgnRect.bottom - clipRgnRect.top,
                   m_alphaBlackDC, clipRgnRect.left, clipRgnRect.top, SRCCOPY);
        }

        DeleteObject(unionRgn);
        pViewObject->Release();
    }

    m_dirtyFlag = false;
    m_dirtyRects.clear();
    m_dirtyUnionRect.left = m_dirtyUnionRect.top = LONG_MAX;
    m_dirtyUnionRect.right = m_dirtyUnionRect.bottom = -LONG_MAX;
}
}
```

The HDC I am passing to this function is created in the following manner:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;                  
ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));                  
textureDesc.Width = width;                  
textureDesc.Height = height;                  
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;                  
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;                  
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;                  
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                  
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;                  
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;                  
textureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GDI_COMPATIBLE;  
HRESULT hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &m_flashTexture); 


HRESULT hResult;
HDC hDC;
IDXGISurface1 *pSurface = NULL; 
hResult = m_flashTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGISurface1), (void**)&pSurface); 
hResult = pSurface->GetDC(TRUE, &hDC);                  
assert(SUCCEEDED(hResult));  
m_flashPlayer->DrawFrame(hDC);
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? I can't seem to figure out what is going on and why this is casuing a blue screen when if I use Directx 9 obejcts it doesn't.  Is there a better way to do this?

(Also I've tried updating my drivers and they are all up to date).

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You got it to BSOD your computer? Awesome (in a bad way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this was indeed a driver issue.  It works without a problem when I run with my graphics card set to the radeon in my latop, but when I have it on switchable for some reason it still crashes even though it should be selecting my radeon.  I need to have the graphics mode fixed.  Weird, but atleast its not my program I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Can't really tell from code inspection.  I haven't noticed anything blatantly wrong.  There certainly should not be a any BSOD - that part is a driver bug.  What hardware/driver are you running on?

A common reason for driver crashes though is illegally writing to some memory area, often if you're blitting to outside of your DC memory.  I'd double check to verify that your regions are not out of bounds and that m_alphaBlackDC is the same size as dc.

I would also highly, highly recommend testing on another non-related GPU (that doesn't share the same hardware architecture).